# HTAccess Rewrite Rule URL from Meta Title

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite a rule for the url

```
navi.php?a=815&lang=eng
```

and a **meta title**

```
How can I post a Video
```

into

```
/en/How-can-I-post-a-Video
```

Can the Meta Title be fetched somehow to add it to url?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the params in the url, you need to form a url with meta tag title. From the url take the arguements and match with the database and get the result data. This is how the .htaccess will work.

Comment: will make another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make a rewrite rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

This will make your actual php file like so:

```
index.php?params=value&param=value
```

And your actual URL would be like so:

http://url.com/params/param/value/param/value

And in your PHP file you could access your params by exploding this like so:

```
<?php

$params = explode( "/", $_GET['params'] );
for($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i+=2) {

  echo $params[$i] ." has value: ". $params[$i+1] ."<br />";

}

?>
```